# Using fossil embedded documents

Tags: fossil

I'm using `fossil` to manage some home projects and keeping notes in the wiki. After running like this for a few months, I'd like to at least try to use embedded documentation; mainly so as to be able easily to go back to previous versions.

I've studied the website page about [managing project documentation](http://www.fossil-scm.org/xfer/doc/trunk/www/embeddeddoc.wiki) which confirms that this is a technique I want to follow up, but I can't make out how to do it.

I've cut-and-pasted one of my wiki pages and added it to my fossil repo, but I can't work out where it should go in the directory structure to be accessible as described on the above page.

I've tried in a few places none of which worked. The document is currently %fossil-root%\doc\foo.wiki, (I'm on Windows), where %fossil-root% is the directory holding _ _FOSSIL__ (slighly mangled filename because of markdown), but having started a server with `fossil ui`, when I point my browser at `http://localhost:8080/doc/foo.wiki`, fossil presents me with a nicely formatted page saying it can't find *index.html*. I created /doc/index.html to see what would happen, but it made no difference.

Please can someone help me out, and/or point me to an example repository containing embedded documentation or another "how-to" document.

Comment: Note that you can save an awful lot of copy/pasting by pulling pages out of the internal wiki from the command line. "fossil help wiki" will give you details. You could do a "fossil wiki list" and then iterate through each of those with "fossil wiki export". Using a loop (cmd | while do...) in Linux, or (for /F %a in ('cmd') do...) in Windows will help matters somewhat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your document is located in `%fossil-root%\doc\foo.wiki`, you can access it at the following URL:

`http://localhost:8080/doc/trunk/doc/foo.wiki`

This URL breaks down as follows:

- `http://localhost:8080` is the root URL to access Fossil when you run `fossil ui`
- `/doc` signals that you want to access embedded documentation
- `/trunk` indicates the checkin containing the documentation you wish to access
- `/doc/foo.wiki` is the path of the document inside the repository

Instead of `trunk`, you can also specify a tag, or a branch name, or even a hexadecimal checkin identifier.

In the URL you were using, `http://localhost:8080/doc/foo.wiki`, **foo.wiki** is interpreted as the *checkin name*, and no document path is specified, which logically means Fossil won't find anything.

As for an example repository containing embedded documentation, the homepage of the Fossil website itself is a prime example:

https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki

where

- `https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html` is Fossil's root URL
- `/doc` indicates a request for embedded documentation
- `/trunk` indicates we want to fetch files from the trunk
- `/www/` is the [path to the requested file](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/dir?ci=trunk&name=www) inside the repository
- `index.wiki` is the name of the file inside the repository.

So, in the ['trunk' branch](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/timeline?r=trunk) of the repository, the file [www/index.wiki](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/finfo?name=www/index.wiki) contains the home page of the Fossil website.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to put the documentation under the `%fossil-root%\www\` directory (or any other directory under version control) in your repository and then you can, for example, add the following line to your header's mainmenu section to link to it:

```
html "<a href='$home/doc/trunk/www/foo.wiki'>Documentation</a>\n"
```

As I said, it can be any directory under version control. To test this, pick any file in the repository, let's say a README file at the top level, and go to `http://localhost:8080/doc/trunk/README`. You should see the README file load up in your browser in a raw text format. By putting wiki or html files under a particular directory such as `www` you make it easy to organize the files that you specifically want rendered as documentation, which makes it easier to link to them.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I was probably missing something blingingly obvious :-(

Comment: This answer is not correct: you're not "interfering" at all, your URL simply isn't complete. See my anser for an explanation. OP can keep his documentation in a `doc` directory just fine.

Comment: @Martijn thanks for clearing that up. I removed the erroneous section.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/embeddeddoc.wiki

After fossil 1.33, just prepare your document in the repository.
If the wiki file is put in

```
/doc/index.wiki
```

And use web browser to setup -> Admin -> Configuration.
There is a "**Index Page**" field, fill in your main index.html.
For example:

```
/doc/trunk/doc/index.wiki
```

Or if you just want the released version:

```
/doc/<version>/doc/index.wiki
```